# Why do I get a feeling on my forehead as if someone is touching it during meditation?

Tags: meditation, meditation-effects, yoga

I do meditate sometimes,not everyday.

After 5 to 10 minutes during meditation I start getting a feeling  on my forehead as if someone is touching in it.

Sometimes after listening to binaural waves or do yoga, I get this same feeling.

I understand that something is happening to the pineal gland.But my friends who meditate they don't get this, its only me.

What exactly happens here and how does it work? Can someone explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to ones past store of conditioning one gets different experiences. The main thing is not to attach too much importance to these experiences as thinking about it will be a distraction main task at hand which is the meditation and also perhaps a source of attachment or aversion on how you react to it which is also decremental to meditation.

Comment: Okay. Understood. But what do you mean by - 'Due to ones past store of conditioning'  ? @Suminda Sirinath Dharmasena

Comment: [Saṅkhāra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saṅkhāra) manifests as some experience or sensation. When meditating, at least when doing it properly, one is not accumulating new [Saṅkhāra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saṅkhāra). Then past [Saṅkhāra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saṅkhāra) arises as some experience or sensation. This varies from person to person and time to time as no 2 beings have the same store of [Saṅkhāra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saṅkhāra).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that this is a quite normal phenomenon. However, it is nothing to be concerned about, and there is nothing in the Buddhist teachings in the ways of interpreting this as something special.

Rather, there is the teaching of noticing the sensation as just a sensation - as one of the six sense inputs - and noticing the feeling that arises from it as just a feeling. The purpose is to not get caught up in sensations like these, but being mindfully aware, notice them, acknowledge them and by knowing them for just sensations, remaining equanimously unattached to them.

I would suggest that with patient endurance, including this as just a phenomenon of your practice, deliberately avoiding getting enchanted by it or averse to it.

Answer (score 0):

You might be concentrating too hard, causing stress in your forehead.

Answer (score 0):

It's very normal and common for people to feel the sensation such as someone is touching a particular area, or ants crawling on your skin. That comes as a natural result of relaxation. The conditions of the body are always changing, so that's likely to change. The underlying principle at work, is when you deeply relax, force pervades through the entire body. If your energy channels are open, then this will be experienced as the 4 jhanas described with similes in AN 5.28. If your channels aren't open yet, then the force will feel uncomfortable, itchy, strange, and painful wherever the force is hitting energy channel blockage.

Answer (score 0):

I’m experiencing the exact same thing.. it felt like there’s someone pushing their forefinger on your forehead. I tried my best to not focus on the sensation and to recenter my attention to the breath but to no avail, the strange feeling crawls to my neck and back that it became too difficult to concentrate so.. I opened my eyes :(

Comment: Hello, and welcome! I would encourage you to post this kind of conversational content in the comments of the original question, instead of as an answer, to keep the answer posts focused on providing answers.